# How to find the velocity of point of intersection?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, vectors

[image]

**My approach:** The velocity of the point of intersection **u** will be in horizontal direction due to symmetry about x-axis.The velocity **v** of the rod makes angle $\theta$ with the vertical.Thus, $v\sin \theta=u$.

But the correct answer is A. Can anyone please point out where am I wrong?

Comment: I have not clear if with theta they mean 45° or 90°....because if it is 45° then 1 and 4 are the same thing! You just need to sum the two velocities, what you did is to calculate the velocity of one rod along the x-axis

Comment: No, it is not fixed.It is just a variable angle..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR You have correctly identified that the intersection point does not travel along the vertical axis, but your conclusion about the horizontal velocity is not correct. I show here how to solve this problem by following: (i) *geometric approach*, from which you will see what is the problem with your conclusion, and (ii) *algebraic approach*, which is in my opinion much more straightforward for this particular problem.

---

### Geometric approach

Let rod $A$ be the one with negative slope. If the positive horizontal axis goes along the dashed line to the right, then velocity of the rod $A$ is

$$\vec{v}_{A/0} = v \angle \bar{\theta} = v ( \sin\theta \hat{\imath} + \cos\theta \hat{\jmath})$$

where $\bar{\theta} = 90^\circ - \theta$. Here you assumed that the intersection horizontal velocity is simply $v \sin\theta$, which is incorrect. That is horizontal velocity of a point (particle) on the rod, which is not the same as the intersection. See figure below for geometric explanation.

[image: Geometric approach]

<sup>Figure: Geometric approach to calculate intersection velocity. The two red lines are of same length.</sup>

The intersection horizontal displacement $\Delta x$ can be calculated as

$$\frac{\Delta x}{\sin 90^\circ} = \frac{v \Delta t}{\sin \theta} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \boxed{\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{v}{\sin\theta} = v \cdot \mathrm{cosec}(\theta)}$$

where $\Delta x / \Delta t$ equals intersection velocity.

---

### Algebraic approach

Let's describe the two rods as lines and place them in a (fixed) Cartesian coordinate system. The line equations are then

$$y_1 = x \tan\theta_1 \qquad y_2 = -x \tan\theta_2$$

The lines travel at certain velocity, but their slope remains constant. This means that the line offset changes in time (see figure below). It takes only a little bit of geometry to show that the offset magnitude is $vt/\cos\theta$ and the line equations become

$$y_1(t) = x(t) \tan\theta_1 - \frac{v_1 t}{\cos\theta_1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_2(t) = -x(t) \tan\theta_2 + \frac{v_2 t}{\cos\theta_2}$$

Your problem is actually a simple version with $\theta_1 = \theta_2 \equiv \theta$ and $v_1 = v_2 \equiv v$

$$y_1(t) = x(t) \tan\theta - \frac{v t}{\cos\theta} \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_2(t) = -x(t) \tan\theta + \frac{v t}{\cos\theta}$$

[image: Algebraic approach]

<sup>Figure: Algebraic approach to calculate intersection velocity. Line offset changes in time.</sup>

Coordinates of the intersection are found from the condition $y_1(t) = y_2(t)$

$$x_i(t) = \frac{v t}{\sin\theta} \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_i(t) = 0$$

The intersection velocity components are

$$v_{i,x} = \frac{d}{dt} x_i(t) = \frac{v}{\sin\theta} = v \cdot \mathrm{cosec}(\theta) \qquad \text{and} \qquad v_{i,y} = \frac{d}{dt} y_i(t) = 0$$

and the intersection velocity magnitude is

$$\boxed{v_i = \sqrt{v_{i,x}^2 + v_{i,y}^2} = v \cdot \mathrm{cosec} (\theta)}$$

Comment: Can you please tell what is offset?

Comment: @AbhinavLenka I added a drawing to the answer. Please check if it answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I have now got a clear picture of what's happening .

Comment: I completely understood the solution provided by you but can you point out the mistake in my calculations(Did I take the wrong components of the velocity? etc.)

Comment: @AbhinavLenka I updated my answer, see if it helps with your last question.

Comment: Yes, I have understood my mistake now.